# deleting a row of line in a text file using java

Tags: java, file, file-io, delete-row

I'm having a hard time deleting a row of lines in a text file, I've use this code but i end up deleting all the lines instead, need some help.

```java
    try //vacation leave/
{
    File inputFile = new File("Adlawan" + code1);
    File tempFile = new File("AdalwanTempFile");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String lineToRemove = "AdlawanJan2012";
    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        //trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) 
        {
         writer.write(currentLine); 
        }
    }   
    writer.close();
    reader.close();

    if(!inputFile.delete())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not rename file");
        return;
    }
    if(!tempFile.renameTo(inputFile))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not rename file");


}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ");
}
```

The data on the file looks like this:

AdlawanJan2012  Vacation-Leave-Credits  -0.6875
AdlawanFeb2012  Vacation-Leave-Credits  -0.6875
AdlawanMar2012  Vacation-Leave-Credits  -0.6875

Desired result after trimming the lines:

AdlawanFeb2012  Vacation-Leave-Credits  -0.6875
AdlawanMar2012  Vacation-Leave-Credits  -0.6875

Thank you...

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to delete line in a file if the line starts with the **"lineToRemove"** variable, in that case you might want to use **"startsWith"** method instead of **"equal"** method.

```
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    //trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
    if(!trimmedLine.startsWith(lineToRemove)) 
    {
        // if current line not start with lineToRemove then write to file
        writer.write(currentLine); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i was able to delete two lines but the line that was deleted were the lines, AdlawanFeb2012 Vacation-Leave-Credits -0.6875 and AdlawanMar2012 Vacation-Leave-Credits -0.6875. I want to delete the line (AdlawanJan2012 Vacation-Leave-Credits -.06875.  Or to be more precise I wanted to delete a specific lines, in this case (AdlawanJan2012 Vacation-Leave-Credits -.06875) Thank you so much for the help.:)

Comment: I think you forgot to add "!" in if condition that why the other lines got deleted. it should be "if(!trimmedLine.startsWith(lineToRemove))".

Comment: yes thank you very much, i did forgot...(:  thank you so much again. the startWith method was the key.

Answer (score 1):

`trim()` method only removes leading and trailing white spaces and not characters after white space.

```
String lineToRemove = "AdlawanJan2012";
```

....

```
String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
if(trimmedLine.substring(0, 14).equals(lineToRemove)) {
    //Your deletion logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'a a good idea to read the file content line by line and copy them to another file(temporal file) preferably a Random Access file and omit the line you want to remove. just copy the rest to the temporal file and omit the line(s) you want to delete. then rename the file to original name. No samples Please. I need you to do this on your own that way you'll learn all by your self. good luck